# Why would you use a feedback resistor on a logic buffer?

Tags: feedback, buffer, phototransistor

Please excuse my poorly drawn photo-interrupter circuit.  It is used for external home sensing where a flag will interrupt the light source, turning off the phototransistor.

[image: Home Sensing Circuit]

I'm just curious as to why somebody would include the feedback 47.5k resistor here.  From my understanding, it is parallel to the 20k resistor when the home signal is high, and is in parallel with the phototransistor when the home signal is low.  This would increase the current when the phototransistor is off and have a negligible effect when the phototransistor is on.  The 74LVC1G17 already has hysteresis so I am just asking what the benefits of this resistor are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resistor adds additional hysteresis beyond what the chip provides. With the nature of what the internet is these days quite possibly you may have found a circuit idea that was designed before the time that the a Schmidt Trigger type IC was used in the circuit.

It is quite common for photo detectors to operate with very long rise and fall times. When a non Schmidt Trigger type IC chip buffer is used the slow transition signal at the output of the opto coupler can cause the buffer chip to transition multiple times. In some applications this is not a problem bit in others such as a counting application it can be a big problem.

Comment: Considering the transitions, the feedback resistor helps drop the voltage by supplying more current from a high-to-low transition.  And from a low-to-high transition, it provides a momentary voltage divider which will provide a logic high.

Do you think I could get away with just using a 10k pullup resistor and removing the feedback resistor?

Comment: @dsizzle83 - You can remove the feedback resistor if you want. I see no particular value to it as the buffer chip is already a Schmitt-Trigger Buffer. If you have access to an oscilloscope it may be interesting for you to actually study the effect slow edges from the opto device have on the output of the buffer with and without the resistor. .... With regard to changing to a 10K pullup resistor. You can experiment with that. Two low value of resistor may not allow the transistor output section of the opto device to pull all the way to GND.

Comment: I have a new board with 10k on them but the collector current at the operating point I'm at is only 0.5 A and very nonlinear in that region.  I'm going to increase to 20k on the next spin but it is working for now.  The circuit above is from a legacy product so I probably should've kept it the same but I didnt... There was an issue with the circuit so I thought it might be because of my omitting the FB resistor.  Turns out it was a micro-step resolution issue with the motor so it works for now.  I am curious to see the transitions on the scope though.  There is a long ribbon cable connected.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's somebody's attempt to "improve" the Schmitt trigger performance of the device, which already has Schmitt trigger inputs (inputs with hysteresis), as you noted.

Since the switching point (voltage level) for most digital devices are only roughly defined (as opposed to an analog comparator, for instance), this falls into the category of a hack, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the two resistors could be used to set the flag positions at which the circuit turns on or off.

To use a homing switch like this, you can move the actuator toward it fairly quickly, until the switch closes, and then move it back slowly so you can precisely determine the position at which it opens again.

The distance between those two positions needs to be big enough to take up any backlash in the actuator mechanism, and let the actuator accelerate to constant speed before the switch reopens.

In addition, you may want to set the position at which the switch reopens to the point at which the circuit is most sensitive (max dV/dx) so that the position measurement is as accurate as possible.

If you care about the precise positions where the switch turns on and off, then it's unlikely that the hysteresis build into the Schmitt trigger will be exactly what you want.